# dom-repeat Firebase data in Polymer

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer

I have a template that returns an amount from a Firebase realtime database, and it is correctly mapped, and returns a value when the `path="/orders"`. However, when I change the path to `path="/orderHistory/[[user.uid]]"` with the same data structure stored at the location, nothing is returned.

The `user` auth object is properly populated, as I have other elements that are returning data properly using this pattern.

```
  <firebase-auth user="{{user}}"></firebase-auth>
  <firebase-document path="/orders" data="{{orders}}"></firebase-document>

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_toArray(orders)}}">
    <p3>{{item.amount}}</p3>
  </template>
```

...

```
_toArray: function (orders) {
     return Object.keys(orders).map(function (key) {
       return {
         date: Date(key),
         amount1: orders[key]['Item']['Amount']
       };
     });
   }
```

...

I am trying to store and return order data... and the JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
  "1473829170599" : {
    "0" : {
      "Item" : {
        "Amount" : 16,
        "QR" : "Bw16Bb14Ni17",
        "Quantity" : 2
      }
    },
  "hasFabbed" : 0,
  "hasPaid" : 0,
  "hasShipped" : 0
}
```

How can I return cart data for a user with Polymer's `dom-repeat` pattern?

Comment: Firstly, you don't need the _toArray method, the firebase will return an array for you.
Secondly you need to use firebase-query in this case not firebase-document and it should work.

Comment: That was my original strategy, and I got that pattern working for a simple note taking store/retrieval, but now with this shopping cart I am getting an error: `[dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for `items`, found Object {}`

Comment: if you have more than one element in your orders it will return an array

Comment: OK, got it working with `firebase-query`.  Thanks Salaheldin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<firebase-query>` instead of `<firebase-document>`.